# How can I convert version 1.0 edmx file content in to POJO's?

Tags: odata, edmx, olingo

I want this in hybris project. i have added dependencies and plug in  pojogen-maven-plugin for 4.6.0 version. But I get error for Navigation property in `EDMX`.

Invocation of method 'getNavigationType' in  class `org.apache.olingo.ext.pojogen.V4Utility` threw exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at entityType.vm
```

Please not none of my entity types in `EDMX` have navigation property as key .

Comment: Hi any one having any inputs.please do share..

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple of things that could go wrong here like.

The Navigation property you have defined might not be correct or there could be a bug in the `V4Utility` class itself.

What I would recommend is that you debug the code with other projects that do something similar. e.g. [OData to OpenAPI  converter](https://github.com/oasis-tcs/odata-openapi/tree/master/tools) or [OpenAPI.NET.OData Converter](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET.OData). You can try parsing your $metadata EDMX with these tool. If they can its most likely a bug in the `V4Utility` class itself